# Adding columns if available

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have 2 tables
1st table consist of 10 rows of acnumber column and 10 rows of opening_balance column.
2nd table consists of 3 of those acnumber in a column having made transaction several times
mentioned in transaction_type column as 'Deposit' or 'Withdrawal' and transaction_amount column .

so I have to select all acnumber and their deposits made i.e opening balance+deposits.If no transaction available in table 2 then add opening balance and 0.  I tried something like this

```
select a1.acnumber,a1.opening_balance+if (a1.acnumber not in (a2.acnumber),0,sum(a2.transaction_amount))
from account a1 left join trandetails a2
on a1.acnumber=a2.acnumber
where a2.transaction_type like'Deposit'
group by a2.acnumber;
```

But it returns only acnumber mentioned in both tables.Any suggestions???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need several changes to the query.  The `where` is undoing the `left outer join` for instance.  You should move that condition to the `on` clause.  Also, the `group by` columns should be the columns in the `select` that are not in aggregation functions.

So, try this

```
select a1.acnumber, a1.opening_balance + coalesce(sum(a2.transaction_amount), 0)
from account a1 left join
     trandetails a2
     on a1.acnumber = a2.acnumber and
        a2.transaction_type like 'Deposit'
group by a1.acnumber, a1.opening_balance;
```